# Confusion about 'create Unsubscribe() using store.subscribe() method in Redux'

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am learning how to create **Unsubscribe()** using **store.subscribe()** method.
Below is the code. I don't understand the logic: why we use **store.subscribe** method to declare unsubscribe constant as an unsubscribe function for the store. (literally, subscribe should subscribe 'something' for the store, right?)

```
import store from './store';

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(
    () => console.log("Store changed!", store.getState())
);

store.dispatch({
    type: "bugAdded",
    payload: {
        description: "Bug1"
    }
});

unsubscribe();

store.dispatch({
    type: "bugRemoved",
    payload: {
        id: 1
    }
});
```

Also, please look at the following modified code: even only declare the **constant unsubscribe**, the console still executes the **store.subscribe** method.

```
import store from './store';

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(
    () => console.log("Store changed!", store.getState())
);

store.dispatch({
    type: "bugAdded",
    payload: {
        description: "Bug1"
    }
});

// unsubscribe();

store.dispatch({
    type: "bugRemoved",
    payload: {
        id: 1
    }
});
```

the above code has the same output as the following code (confused, anyone could explain)

```
import store from './store';

store.subscribe(
    () => console.log("Store changed!", store.getState())
);

store.dispatch({
    type: "bugAdded",
    payload: {
        description: "Bug1"
    }
});

store.dispatch({
    type: "bugRemoved",
    payload: {
        id: 1
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

store.subscribe will just create a suscription to our store, it will be listening the store and waiting for it to change, every time the store changes it will execute the callback we passed to it. When we subscribe to the store, it returns a function to unregister that subscription later that we can call whenever we need.

You could read more about it on the [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/store)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you take a look at the last two codes? I couldn't figure out why they have the same output. One: assign STORE.SUBSCRIBE method to a UNSUBSCRIBE constant (my understanding is even though I declare a constant, it should not execute if I don't use this constant); The other: simply call STORE.SUBSCRIBE method.

Comment: The one who simply calls the store.subscribe will remain subscribed to the store forever, while the one who assigns it to an unsubscribe variable, will access to the unsubscribe function later to remove the store subscription